# Getting the Current User

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, laravel-5, laravel-spark

I am sorry for the dumb question, but I am new at this programming thing and having fun. How do I get the current user in a base Laravel Spark project? I know what the Laravel Spark documentation says, but I can't seem to get the information even with that. I guess I just need an example. Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can access the current authorized user by using the Auth facade. `$user = Auth::user();` Make sure to add `use Auth;` at the top of your file!

Adding on top of this, if you just need something small like the logged-in users's ID, you can say `Auth::id()`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks so much!